# Logging my users into other services, how to store their passwords?

Tags: passwords

I am starting a service for students at my school which requires them giving me their user account information for our school's web system so that I can automate some annoying tasks for them. I will be logging them in using CURL but I am having trouble figuring out how to store their passwords in a secure method. With most web services, passwords are encrypted then stored and when logging in, we only compare the encrypted passwords. This is much different though. Since I will be sending their passwords via HTTP requests, it's required I am able to decrypt their passwords back into original text. How would you recommend I go about storing and retrieving them?

Answer (score 1):

That might not be the answer you are looking at, but if you are going to store user's credentials for a third party service, there is no way to secure the storage with software only. As you mentioned it yourself, your app needs to be able to retrieve from that store the original credentials, in order to impersonate the user. And if your app can do it, so can any other code running on that box.

Thus, the only real solution is to ensure that only your software is running on the box. That assumes physical security as well, limited access to the machine, full audit and lowering the attack surface as much as possible, by turning off all unnecessary services.

On a separate note, if the school services support access delegation (through OAuth for example), you should consider going that route, and get out of the credentials storing business.